# Pandas DataFrame create new csv column based on two other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a new column in a csv called BTTS, which is based on two other columns, FTHG and FTAG. If FTHG & FTAG are both greater than zero, BTTS should be 1. Otherwise it should be zero.

What's the best way to do this in pandas / numpys?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what the **best** way is. But here is one solution using pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method:

```
df.loc[((df['FTHG'] > 0) & (df['FTAG'] > 0)),'BTTS'] = 1
df['BTTS'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Another solution using pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

```
def check_greater_zero(row):
    return 1 if row['FTHG'] > 0 & row['FTAG'] > 0 else 0

df['BTTS'] = df.apply(check_greater_zero, axis=1)
```

EDIT:

As stated in the comments, the first, vectorized, implementation is more efficient.

Comment: your answer contains a fallacy, `apply` is not more efficient, in fact it is less efficient because it is the same as looping over the dataframe. you are better off using a vectorized approach like you have listed in your first snippet

Comment: You are right! I was testing my code with just a small example in which case the second approach was more efficient than the first approach. But as it was just a very small example I agree: The bigger the DataFrame, the more efficient the first approach is.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the best way to do it but this works :)

```
df['BTTS'] = [1 if x == y == 1 else 0 for x, y in zip(df['FTAG'], df['FTHG'])]
```